# Create a new page without creating a new file

Tags: php

```
<?php
$content = <<<EOL
<head>
</head>
<body>
New page
EOL;

mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db("...");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY ID")
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo $row['name'];
}

$content .= <<<EOL
</body>
</html>
EOL;
$file = "page.php";
$open = fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($open, $content);
fclose($open);
?>
```

Im trying to make a simple CMS, Let say the user is on the page "create page", the code above is just an example which is I took from here https://forums.techguy.org/threads/creating-a-new-page-automatically-with-php.832639/

This should create a new file `"page.php"` so we have now a link which is `www.mysite.com/page.php` which works and accessible.

But, what if a user create a hundred pages then there will be a hundred php files which I think is not good right? So is there any way to create a page without creating files?

Another Example I want to achieve is let say I create a page `"mypage.php"` and it should NOT create a new file. Now when I type the url `"www.mysite.com/mypage.php"` should be accessible.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should stop thinking of "web pages" being based on files. That is typically _not_ the case! Content of web pages is stored in databases. You typically use a router script as a file (and maybe a few includes) which processes the arguments to the http request, so what page is requested. The router script fetches the content of those pages from the database, renders that page and sends it out to the client.

Comment: @arkascha, okay let say it is store on the database, so how can we make an accessible link `www.mysite.com/mypage.php` ?  I made a link but it is internal server error when I click it.. Should I use htacces file to make it accessible?

Comment: @arkascha is correct. It may help you to have a look at the introductory series for [laravel](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017) as it does exactly what you're describing

Comment: You indeed typically use rewriting logic to map requests to the central routing script. That does not necessarily mean `.htaccess` style files, it makes much more sense to implement such rewriting rules in the http servers host configuration. The rewriting logic hands over requests to maybe `www.mysite.com/myotherpage` to `/index.php?page=myotherpage`. That router script can then evaluate `$_GET['page']` and fetch the requested page from the database. That means you have a dynamic system with static files and also allows for pretty urls at the same time.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @arkascha !

Comment: But I wonder why I got downvoted? seriously if they dont know the answer then leave it alone, or if there's something wrong with my post then tell it on comment. I wonder whats wrong.

Comment: Not sure, it might be that some folks consider your question as an indication that you did not do much research. That is something that might lead to downvotes. Most people understand this place such that answers to specific implementation details are given, not to questions asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

There is such thing as "Link parameters", you can have one page with multiple checks. For example.

```
yoursite.com/index.php?page=home
yoursite.com/index.php?page=about
yoursite.com/index.php?page=info
```

To get these parameters use $_GET request.

```
$my_site = $_GET['page'];
```

So you could do this at the end on your index.php

```
if($my_site == 'home') {
  //home content
} else if( $my_site == 'about') {
  //about content
}
```

That way you have index.php (Which is default index file) and you check which page he is on. Use those links for your a href's.

Another option would be "Laravel" - you could use it for creating similar stuff you want to achieve, if you are not advanced in PHP and learning it, I would recommend to learn laravel anyways, it would provide you with stability and security, that you wouldn't be able to provide doing custom system platform. However if you are making a small project, learning is all ways fine. Go for which one you want.